DOSKEY shortcut for kubectl logs command
I have 3 different apps (my-app-1, my-app-2, my-app-3)
I am trying to add doskey shortcuts for the logs
i.e. for the below command
kubectl logs my-app-1-<SOME_RANDOM_POD_ID>

My intention is to NOT enter anything on the prompt, but somehow use the shortcuts directly to run the "kubectl logs <APP_1/2/3>" command
doskey klogsapp1=kubectl get pods $B grep $1.*Running $B cut -d " " -f1 $B xargs kubectl logs -c my-app-1
doskey klogsapp2=kubectl get pods $B grep $1.*Running $B cut -d " " -f1 $B xargs kubectl logs -c my-app-2
doskey klogsapp3=kubectl get pods $B grep $1.*Running $B cut -d " " -f1 $B xargs kubectl logs -c my-app-3

For some reason, the above commands are not working. is there any way by which I can have a shortcut for the same ?
Not sure if something like below would work;
doskey klogsapp1=kubectl get pods | grep $1.*Running | cut -d " " -f1 | xargs kubectl logs -c my-app-1

doskey klogsapp1=kubectl get pods | grep $1.*Running | cut -d " " -f1 | xargs kubectl logs -c my-app-1

With above, I am getting below error
error: expected 'logs [-f] [-p] (POD | TYPE/NAME) [-c CONTAINER]'.
POD or TYPE/NAME is a required argument for the logs command
doskey klogsapp1=kubectl get pods | grep $1.*Running | cut -d " " -f1 | xargs -I{} kubectl logs -c my-app-1 {}

Unfortunately, it's not possible to achieve this using doskey shortcuts without using them in the command prompt. Instead you can create batch file and associate them with doskey macros. Create a new file for each app such as logs1.bat, logs2.bat, logs3.bat and add the command kubectl logs my-app-1-<SOME\_RANDOM\_POD\_ID\>.  Now open the command prompt and use the doskey command to define macros that execute batch files. Once defined, you can use it directly in the prompt which will execute the corresponding batch files that contain logs commands for each app.
